# Why is the content of my Text not getting displayed correct along 10dp padding from end in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have created a Row and added two inner Rows with Text in first Row to be at the center of the screen like this [image]

In same parent Row, I have created another child row where I am have created a Text with a string "Close" So I want it to display to the right side of the first Row with padding of end=10.dp. But right now it's showing close to middle with some characters from word are missing.

```
@Composable
fun SpeechScreen1(navController: NavController) {
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val swipeThreshold = 200 // Adjust this threshold as needed
    
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(top = 20.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .width(118.dp)
            .height(28.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
              Text(text = "Audio Sample")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(30.dp))
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .width(38.dp)
            .height(24.dp)
            .padding(end = 10.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()) {
            Text(text = "Close")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove width from `Row` which contains `Close` text and replace it with `wrapContentWidth()`

Answer (score 0):

You made your Composable very complicated.
Using inner Rows is not good idea.
consider using this :

```
@Composable
fun SpeechScreen1() {
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val swipeThreshold = 200 // Adjust this threshold as needed

    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(top = 20.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            Text(text = "Audio Sample",)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(30.dp))
            Text(text = "Close")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it be a bad idea and how does this answer the question?

Comment: Because Row and Columns are not skippable.

Comment: @HosseinShahmohammadi That explains nothing. To me, at least. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

There is one key thing that I think people are not fully aware of about `Modifier` **order matters**(*for things interacting with each other*).

```
Row(modifier = Modifier
        .width(38.dp)
        .height(24.dp)
        .padding(end = 10.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()) {
        Text(text = "Close")
    }
```

This will limit the `width` of the content to `38.dp` and apply padding to that - making the usable width for the content `28.dp`. (`.fillMaxWidth()` here doesn't do anything)

```
Row(modifier = Modifier
    .background(color = Color.Red)
    .padding(end = 10.dp)
    .background(color = Color.Green)
    .wrapContentWidth() //.width(38.dp) 
    .wrapContentHeight() //.height(24.dp) 
) {
    Text(text = "Close")
}
```

This will set the end padding to the content of the `Row` and then it will limit it to the `38.dp`

Comment: My Tech Lead has told me to use wrapContentWidth() and wrapContentHeight() instead of .width(38.dp).height(24.dp), so I should not use manual dimsensions n anywhere . How can I implement it then?

Comment: @vilnius19 I updated the answer and added background color so if you try it you can better see what/why it is happening.